# sending email issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have config  email in codeigniter

```
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => '465',
                    'smtp_user' => '-----',
                    'smtp_pass' => '-----',
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'charset' => 'utf-8'

$this->load->library('email', $this->session->userdata('config'));
            $this->email->from('new@gmail.com', 'Rtlx Team');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $message = "Dear ";
            $this->email->subject('Rtlx Team - Account Verification');
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();
            $this->email->clear();
```

But it shows following errors:

> Message: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mail server at "localhost" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
>
> Message: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: im sure i had a similar problem, it was because the email library expects the smtp username and password to be sent, to get around this issue you may need to extend the email library so it doesn't check the connection. It does this because the SMTP connection fails so it falls back on the `mail` function.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html and your smtp settings...

Answer (score 0):

You are loading email library incorrectly as `$this->load->library('email',$this->session->userdata('config'));`.

so **load it as `$this->load->library('email');` and initialize it as `$this->email->initialize($this->session->userdata('config'));`**

in below example i have taken `$config` array but you can take your own configuration in session also as in question you have used. but set all option as i have set in `$config` you can set it in session's variable.

full code below:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'your@mail.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => 'yourpassword', // change it to yours
    'mailtype' => 'html',// it can be text or html
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    );
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('your@mail.com',"Rtlx Team");
    $this->email->to('receiver@mail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Subject');
    $this->email->message('Sample message');
    if (!$this->email->send()) 
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger()); 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Your e-mail has been sent!';
    }
```